# Storing Form Data to google sheet using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, google-sheets

I want to upload all of my form data to google sheet. I tried on it but still can't store data on google sheet.
Here my Gsheet Api Call

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
          "sheetId": 0
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredValue": {
            "stringValue": "Adnan1",
            "stringValue": "Adnan2",
            "stringValue": "Adnan3",
            "stringValue": "Adnan4"
          }
        },
        "fields": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using this i update only one cell i know it's due to dimension but is there any way to store all of my form data to gsheet. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You're using [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest) which is intended to repeat the same value in the selected range of cells. You could use a [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) and use the `rows` field to set the values. The below example sets 3 rows values to the first column:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateCells": {
        "range": {
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "endRowIndex": 3,
          "sheetId": 0
        },
        "rows": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "Adnan1"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "Adnan2"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredValue": {
                  "stringValue": "Adnan3"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "fields": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i want to add multiple data in each row, but it's update one row each time with new data.

Comment: You can add multiple data in each row with [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest), just add more values.